# Ruby Net::IMAP sort method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imap

I am using Net::IMAP to connect to gmail or any other IMAP server.

It works great however when I try to sort it returns an error and I can't figure out why.

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, true)
imap.login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
imap.examine('INBOX')
imap.sort(["DATE"], ['ALL'], "US-ASCII")
```

Will return

```
Net::IMAP::BadResponseError in ExampleController#index

Unknown command: SORT
```

Any ideas why this would be happening??

Comment: try running the same command through telnet by making a client connection.